# Creating a div with a scroll bar

Tags: html, css

I'm tearing my hair out over this one, basically I'm making a page which has an absolute positioned output panel across the bottom of it, with the content in the top 80% of the window:

```
<div id="pageContent">
    ..Content..
</div>

<div id="outputPanel">
</div>
```

I've disabled the scroll bar on the body as I want two scroll bars, one on the page content, and one on the output.

```
body {
    overflow: hidden;
}

#pageContent {
    height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
}

#outputPanel{
    height: 20%;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

The output panel work, but the content doesn't, and here is why I think it doesn't; when I inspect the content div, it says it's 2600px in height (which is the height of the content it contains), but I set it to 100%, so shouldn't it be 100% of the height of the body?  which should be 100% of the window?

When I explicitly set the height of the content to say 300px, it works as expected, but the thing is, I can't set the height as explicit pixel count because the window might resize..

How can I get the div to be 100% of the window, and is there any way to do it without using javascript, as I'm trying to do it in as pure html as possible.

Answer (score 0):

```
body {
    overflow: hidden;
}

#pageContent {
    height: 100%;
    overflow: scroll;
}

#outputPanel {
    height: 20%;
    overflow: scroll;
}
```

Comment: You realize he has the id pageContent styled twice right? The second one is going to overwrite the first.

Comment: Sorry, I just copy the code and do not realize that.But I cannot edit it now

Comment: Yup, figured that. All good, just pointing it out so you could fix.

Answer (score 0):

What I think is both the divs are inside body tag so it should be 80% and 20% as per your requirement as div pagecontent and div outputpanel are say child div of body...or else do one thing

```
<body>
  <div id="wrapper">
         <div id="pageContent">
         </div>
         <div id="outputPanel">
          </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Css goes Like this

```
  body {
         overflow: hidden;
  }
  #wrapper {
      height: 100%;
     overflow: scroll;
   }

  #pageContent {
      height: 80%;
     overflow: scroll;
   }

   #wrapper #outputPanel {
       height: 20%;
       overflow: scroll;
    }
```

try this and tell me whether i got your question right...

Comment: Ok I figured it out.  The issue was that the div tag was picking up the size of the content, this is because height was set to 100%, so it got it from the body, which was 100%, which got it from the html, which wasn't set.  Not sure why not setting it put it at that size, but explicitly setting the html tag's height to 100% sorted it.

Answer (score 0):

I Think this is what you need  xfx is right but you made a mistake in the question with double  outputPanel

```
   body {
    overflow: hidden;
}

#pageContent {
    height: 100%;
    overflow: scroll;
}

#outputPanel{
    height: 20%;
    overflow: scroll;
}
```

Comment: so I tried this, and I got scrollbars, as you'd expect, but they don't work.  I think the reason is because div#pageContent's height is being computed to the height of the items which is contains, therefore it isn't overflowing.

Comment: actually I'm certain this is the problem, because if I open the console and explicitly change the height of div#pageContent to something like 300px, it works as expected.  So have can I tell div#pageContent that is needs to be 100% the size of the screen, and not 100% the size of the content

Answer (score 0):

*sorry miss-posted as a comment*

OK I figured it out.  The issue was that the div tag was picking up the size of the content, this is because height was set to 100%, so it got it from the body, which was 100%, which got it from the html, which wasn't set.  Not sure why not setting it put it at that size, but explicitly setting the html tag's height to 100% sorted it.